# Localize file name segments in generic makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a generic `Makefile` which a whole bunch of targets that get re-used across projects. For the most part my projects have been in Turkish and so I've used Turkish words for most of the target names. This makes sense as it is what the actual finished files need to be called, and the `Makefile` also takes care of publishing the results.

For example I might have a source `book.md` in my repository. The included `Makefile` has recipies so that you can run `make book-a4.pdf` and get an A4 sized typeset version of the book. But there is a lot more, for example `make book-a4-cilt.pdf` will build an appropriately sized cover or `make-octavo-3b-on.png` will render a 3D model of the book at Octovo size.

This works great, but now I want to allow the `Makefile` to be used as a toolkit and this requires that it work in other languages. The base names for the rules depend on the project so those are not a problem. The paper sizes are a non issue because they aren't localized anyway. But all the other target names become a problem.

For example if the project language is set to English `make book-a4-cover.pdf` needs to do what `make-a4-cilt.pdf` was doing and `make book-octavo-3d-front.png` needs to do what `make book-octavo-3b-on.png` was doing.

Among GNU-Make's variable types there are *not* associative arrays or matrices. I've thought of a couple ways to hack this, but they all feal really dirty. What sort of concept could I go with to enable multi-lingual usage with localized file names without making a mess (more than I already have) of the target definitions?

Comment: It isn't too clear for me. You want a 'general' `Makefile` and want to use in many projects. If `projectA` is english the targets should be `book-a4-cover.pdf`. The spanish `projectB`'s valid target is `book-a4-cilt.pdf`. And many `book-a4-{spanish,english}.pdf` targets. Am I understanding correct?

Comment: @uzsolt That's about right. And somehow they have to map to the same recipes and some of the recipes will need to know how to get from "cilt" to know that that means "cover".

Comment: I think @MadScientist's answer (maybe with some small modifications) will be right in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do for something like this is constructed variable names.  It's not exactly clear to me what you want to do, so I can't really advise you.

You say you want the makefile to be a toolkit.  One option would be to write a generic makefile that used variable names for the different language values, then set those variables differently.

So your toolkit makefile would be something like:

```
$ cat rules.mk
book-a4-$(cover).pdf: ...

book-octavo-3d-$(front).png: ...
```

etc.  Then you can create individual language values, and include that makefile:

```
$ cat Makefile
# English
cover := cover
front := front

include rules.mk

# Turkish
cover := cilt
front := on

include rules.mk
```

Note that any content that isn't variable based on the modified targets in some way would need to go into a separate file so you don't include it twice and override the values.

The languages could also be in their own makefiles, so `include english.mk`, `include turkish.mk`, or whatever.

Or, you could write different makefiles for each language and invoke them recursively, or lots of different ways.